# Deploy a Predictive model created by R in production server

Tags: deployment, model, hive

I have created a random forest predictive model using R and have saved it in my local machine. Now I want to deploy in a server running Hive and predict using this model using the full data set in my Hive data warehouse. Now how do I deploy this model and how do I run this model against Hive full data set.

Can someone help me and share me the code to predict the model I created against the Hive full data set.

I am wondering if I have 10 million rows then how kind of batch size should I use. Even if I take a batch size of 100,000 it would be too time consuming . How others are deploying in production and predicting using large data size.